# fatal: unsafe repository ('/azerothcore' is owned by someone else)

Tags: git, azerothcore

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('/azerothcore' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /azerothcore
--
    Could not find a proper repository signature (hash) - you may need to pull tags with git fetch -t
    Continuing anyway - note that the versionstring will be set to "unknown 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (Archived)"
```

**I'm on Windows 10, docker desktop with git --version 2.36 on the latest master AC branch (07.05)**

Cannot even check current hash [Picture](https://gyazo.com/414a9a96f70557a29f774048180cf6b6)

I've tried everything that is suggested in the related threads. Even disabling that safety function by having `[safe] directory = *` (I'm the only user so it doesn't really matter) in my .gitconfig does not solve this issue.

Edit: I use docker to compile and this pops every time I compile, and no, it started showing after the git security update recently.

Comment: you need to make sure to set that setting **inside docker**

Comment: This is mostly a Docker issue, really. When you start up a virtual host inside Docker, you control the layout of its virtual file systems. That includes whether your home directory—containing your `--global` Git configuration—appears at all inside the virtual host, and if so, where it shows up. The virtual host has virtual users as well, so the virtual user may have a different home directory. You can, if you wish, make *your* home directory *their* home directory, but that's often unwise. So you'll wind up needing a `--global` config for the virtual Git user in the virtual host.

Comment: Once you work through all the Docker-side items here, note that you probably don't want to declare *every* directory safe, but rather just the `/azerothcore` directory. That way you won't be exposing your virtual host to the security issues for which the new safety-checks exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the best way to do it, but I just modified `apps\docker\docker-build-prod.sh` to add `git config --global --add safe.directory /azerothcore` before calling `bash acore.sh compiler build`

Comment: That did solve it! Thanks all for the help and info.
However git now wants to commit changes to that file and if I try to add it to `.gitignore` it wants wants to commit `.gitignore` itself. I tried `.git/info/exclude` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me on Windows 10.

- git config --global --add safe.directory

Ex: git config --global --add safe.directory d:/Dev/project1